# How can I remote desktop into a windows pc with an ethernet to usb adapter on my macbook with low latency?

Tags: network, windows, usb, remote-desktop, ethernet

I wont have a monitor for my pc when I move (and no space to have one) so I'm ordering an hdmi dummy plug and ethernet over usb cable (with a usb c adaptor). I want to control my windows pc using something like anydesk or parsec on my macbook so I can use my windows pc for 3D modeling\rendering. Is this the right approach or should I be using some other type of hardware or software to control my windows pc with my macbook? I essentially want to use my macbook as a monitor for windows pc as efficiently as possible.

Comment: Why not just Microsoft RDC?

Comment: @Tetsujin from what I understood reading online is that Parsec has less latency between a mac and windows machine? If that is the fastest way to do it software wise I will use it. I'm still curious on whether using usb over ethernet for the hardware is the right approach or not

Comment: I used Remote Desktop on my Mac to control a lot of Windows servers/PCs for many years. I would try that first and see how your latency is for your specific use case as it **is** free on the Mac and comes with every Windows PC, and setup takes seconds.